# My js popup is not working dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

My javascript function is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#popup').jPop({
        type: "img",
        gallery: true,
        onClick: '',
        onClose: ''
    });     
});

<a id="popup" href="data:image/jpeg;base64,${mapo.encodedString}"> 
    <img src...> <img> 
</a>
```

Here popup is working well for first tag.

I am removing the old tags `$("#popup").remove();`.

Then after when i am dynamically adding a href tags

```
$("#old").append(" < a id='popup' href.. >< img tag > < / a >");
```

Here after appending the image is not associated with jquery popup for next time.here pop up is not working for this dynamical added image.There is no mistake in adding dynamical tag.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Can you try to trig again jPop after append href tags

Comment: You need to call the jpop function every time you dynamically add the anchor to the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to call `$('#popup').jPop` again after you append the new popup.

maybe split out the jpop creation into a new function

```
function createPopup(){
    $('#popup').jPop({
      type: "img",
      gallery: true,
      onClick: '',
      onClose: ''
    });   
}
```

then you can call in in document ready and after when you append the new image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   createPopup();     
});

$("#old").append(" < a id='popup' href.. >< img tag > < / a >");
createPopup();
```